Sinon sandboxes not stubbing functions in a controller in a express js app
I tried stubbing functions that were in a controller in an express app and when I called the controller function, assertions I wrote throws an error that the stubbed functions are not called or not called with the required arguments. Below is the test file. When I console.log(createUserStub) I get [Function: createUser]. Also, when I tried console.logging the newUser generated in the controller function, the result printed out shows that the actual internal function, createUser was called and not the stubbed function. (The set up files helps in setting up the database. I didn't include them because I crossed the limit specified by stackoverflow). Here is the like to the github: https://github.com/Emmanuel-Ibekwe/trackr-backend
The file directory is test>controller> auth.test.js
const sinon = require("sinon");
const sinonChai = require("sinon-chai");
const chai = require("chai");

chai.use(sinonChai);
const expect = chai.expect;

const authController = require("./../../src/controllers/auth");
const tokenService = require("./../../src/services/token.js");
const authService = require("./../../src/services/auth.js");

const { generatePassword } = require("./../../src/utils/auth.js");
const sendEmailModule = require("./../../src/utils/sendEmail.js");

describe("Signup Controller", () => {
  let res, req, createUserStub, generateTokenStub, sendEmailStub;
  let sandbox;

  const fakeHashedPassword = "fhfhgjkggklgj";
  const fakeId = "hjklkjhghjkjhghjkjh";
  const fakePictureUrl = "www.picture.com";
  const fakeToken = "rhjkljhghjkjhghj";

  const userInput = {
    name: "Emmanuel Ibekwe",
    email: "ibekweemmanuel007@gmail.com",
    password: generatePassword(),
    picture: fakePictureUrl
  };

  const newUser = {
    _id: fakeId,
    name: "Emmanuel Ibekwe",
    email: "ibekweemmanuel007@gmail.com",
    picture: fakePictureUrl
  };

  const fakeCreatedUser = {
    ...userInput,
    password: fakeHashedPassword,
    _id: fakeId
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
    console.log("inside beforeEach");
    createUserStub = sandbox.stub(authService, "createUser");

    createUserStub.resolves(fakeCreatedUser);

    generateTokenStub = sandbox.stub(tokenService, "generateToken");
    generateTokenStub.resolves(fakeToken);

    sendEmailStub = sandbox.stub(sendEmailModule, "sendEmail").resolves();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    console.log("inside afterEach");
    sandbox.restore();
  });

  it("should sign up user successfully", async done => {
    const statusJsonSpy = sandbox.spy();

    res = {
      json: sandbox.spy(),
      status: sandbox.stub().returns({ json: statusJsonSpy })
    };
    req = { body: userInput };

    const next = err => {
      console.log("err", err);
    };

    try {
      await authController.signup(req, res, next);

      // createUserStub();
      expect(createUserStub).to.have.been.calledOnce;
      expect(createUserStub).to.have.been.calledOnceWith(userInput);
      expect(generateTokenStub).to.have.been.calledTwice;
      expect(sendEmailStub).to.have.been.calledOnce;
      expect(res.status).to.have.been.calledOnceWith(201);
      expect(res.json).to.have.been.calledWith({
        message: "sign up successful",
        accessToken: fakeToken,
        refreshToken: fakeToken,
        user: newUser
      });

      done();
    } catch (error) {
      done(error);
    }
  }); //
});


This is the controller
const { createUser, signInUser } = require("./../services/auth.js");
const { generateToken, verifyToken } = require("./../services/token.js");
const createHttpError = require("http-errors");
const User = require("./../models/user.js");
const { sendEmail } = require("./../utils/sendEmail.js");
const PasswordResetCode = require("./../models/PasswordResetCode.js");
const bcryptjs = require("bcryptjs");
const { isPasswordFalse } = require("../utils/validation.js");
const { getRandomSixDigit, generatePassword } = require("./../utils/auth.js");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const { OAuth2Client } = require("google-auth-library");

dotenv.config();

const {
  ADMIN_EMAIL,
  FRONT_END_TESTING_DOMAIN,
  FRONT_END_PRODUCTION_DOMAIN
} = process.env;

const signup = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { name, email, password, picture } = req.body;
    console.log("req.body", { name, email, password, picture });
    const newUser = await createUser({
      name,
      email,
      password,
      picture
    });
    console.log("newUser", newUser);

    const accessToken = await generateToken(
      {
        userId: newUser._id.toString(),
        email: newUser.email
      },
      "1d",
      process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
    );
    console.log("accessToken", accessToken);

    const refreshToken = await generateToken(
      {
        userId: newUser._id.toString(),
        email: newUser.email
      },
      "30d",
      process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET
    );

    await sendEmail({
      code: null,
      to: newUser.email,
      subject: "Trackr Sign up",
      name: newUser.name.split(" ")[0],
      type: "sign up"
    });

    console.log(201);

    res.status(201).json({
      message: "sign up successful",
      accessToken,
      refreshToken,
      user: {
        _id: newUser._id,
        name: newUser.name,
        email: newUser.email,
        picture: newUser.picture
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    if (!error.status) {
      error.status = 500;
    }
    next(error);
  }
};

Here are the codes of the internal functions.
const createHttpError = require("http-errors");
const validator = require("validator");
const bcryptjs = require("bcryptjs");
const User = require("../models/user.js");
const validation = require("./../utils/validation.js");
const { isPasswordFalse } = validation;

const createUser = async userData => {
  const { name, email, password, picture } = userData;
  // console.log("userData", userData);
  if (!name || !email || !password) {
    throw createHttpError.BadRequest("Please fill all fields");
  }

  // console.log("name", name);
  if (!validator.isEmail(email)) {
    throw createHttpError.BadRequest("email is invalid");
  }

  const checkEmail = await User.findOne({ email: email });

  if (checkEmail) {
    throw createHttpError.Conflict("email already exists. Try a new email.");
  }

  if (isPasswordFalse(password)) {
    throw createHttpError.BadRequest(
      "password must be atleast 8 characters and contain atleast an uppercase, a lowercase, a number or a special character"
    );
  }

  const hashedPassword = await bcryptjs.hash(password, 12);
  // console.log("hashedPassword", hashedPassword);
  const user = await new User({
    name,
    email,
    password: hashedPassword,
    picture: picture || DEFAULT_PICTURE_URL
  });

  return user.save();
};


const tokenUtils = require("./../utils/token.js");
const { sign, verify } = tokenUtils;

const generateToken = async (payload, expiresIn, secret) => {
  const token = await sign(payload, expiresIn, secret);
  return token;
};


I tried testing just the createUser function and all tests were passed. Here is the test file.
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const sinon = require("sinon");
const sinonChai = require("sinon-chai");
const chai = require("chai");

chai.use(sinonChai);
const expect = chai.expect;

const authService = require("../../src/services/auth.js");
const bcryptjs = require("bcryptjs");
const User = require("../../src/models/user");
const { generatePassword } = require("../../src/utils/auth");

describe("createUser Service", () => {
  let hashStub, findOneStub, saveStub, sandbox;
  const fakeHashedPassword = "fhfhgjkggklgj";
  const fakeId = "hjklkjhghjkjhghjkjh";
  const fakePictureUrl = "www.picture.com";

  const userInput = {
    name: "Emmanuel Ibekwe",
    email: "ibekweemmanuel007@gmail.com",
    password: generatePassword(),
    picture: fakePictureUrl
  };

  const fakeCreatedUser = {
    ...userInput,
    password: fakeHashedPassword,
    _id: fakeId
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
    hashStub = sandbox.stub(bcryptjs, "hash");
    findOneStub = sandbox.stub(mongoose.Model, "findOne");

    saveStub = sandbox.stub(User.prototype, "save");

    hashStub.resolves(fakeHashedPassword);
    findOneStub.resolves(null);

    saveStub.resolves(fakeCreatedUser);
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore();
  });

  it("should return a newly created user", async () => {
    newUser = await authService.createUser(userInput);

    expect(newUser).to.deep.equal(fakeCreatedUser);
  });

  it("should throw a BadRequest error if name is not provided", async () => {
    try {
      await authService.createUser({ ...userInput, name: undefined });
    } catch (err) {
      //   console.log(err);
      expect(err.status).to.equal(400);
      expect(err.message).to.equal("Please fill all fields");
    }
  });

  it("should throw a BadRequest error if email is invalid", async () => {
    try {
      await authService.createUser({ ...userInput, email: "undefined" });
    } catch (err) {
      //   console.log(err);
      expect(err.status).to.equal(400);
      expect(err.message).to.equal("email is invalid");
    }
  });

  it("should throw a BadRequest error if email is not provided", async () => {
    try {
      await authService.createUser({ ...userInput, email: undefined });
    } catch (err) {
      //   console.log(err);
      expect(err.status).to.equal(400);
      expect(err.message).to.equal("Please fill all fields");
    }
  });

  it("should throw a Conflict error if user already exists", async () => {
    try {
      await authService.createUser({ ...userInput, password: "hhfjdkdlflf" });
    } catch (err) {
      //   console.log(err);
      expect(err.status).to.equal(400);
      expect(err.message).to.equal(
        "password must be atleast 8 characters and contain atleast an uppercase, a lowercase, a number or a special character"
      );
    }
  });

  it("should throw a BadRequest error if password does not meet the required conditions", async () => {
    findOneStub.resolves(fakeCreatedUser);
    try {
      await authService.createUser(userInput);
    } catch (err) {
      expect(err.status).to.equal(409);
      expect(err.message).to.equal("email already exists. Try a new email.");
    }
  });
});



Please provide a [mre], with special emphasis on minimal. Half the code is missing anyway, if not more. You want to make it as simple as possible for others to a) understand your problem, b) reproduce it an c) eventually solve it. A simple code dump will only appeal to a fraction of the users, which in turn reduces the probability of getting a useful answer a great deal. Please [edit] your question accordingly.
